# Webpack - insufficient number of arguments for ReactJs - Spring Boot app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, maven, webpack

I have a Spring Boot application with ReactJs as a frontend part.

I'm trying to configure the build process for the frontend using
the frontend-maven-plugin like so:

```
<!-- tag::frontend-maven-plugin[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <installDirectory>src/main/webapp/invoicing-frontend</installDirectory>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp/invoicing-frontend</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v12.13.1</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.12.1</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>webpack build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>webpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::frontend-maven-plugin[] -->
```

It runs fine until the execution of "webpack build". Here's webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/components/App.js'
    },
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, // include .js files
                enforce: "pre", // preload the jshint loader
                exclude: /node_modules/, // exclude any and all files in the node_modules folder
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'es2017']
                    },
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
        modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules']
    }
};
```

The project directory is as follows:

```
myapp.src.main
    - java
    - webapp
        -myapp-frontend
            -node
            -node_modules
            -public
                -index.html
            -src
                -built
                -components (where React components are)
                -css
                -img
                -js
                -index.js
            -package.json
            -webpack.config.js
```

When the webpack build command is run the following output appears:

> Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found. Alternatively, run
>   'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.
>
> Hash: <....> Version: webpack 4.41.2 Time: 33ms Built
>   at: 2019-12-12 16:34:22
>
> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'build' in
>   'C:\Users\testuser\Projects\myapp\src\main\webapp\myapp-frontend'

I'm pretty sure the error comes from an incorrect webpack.config.js but I seem to be unable to fix it myself.
Any help with resolving the error is appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you execute webpack from the command line, executing it from the root dir of myapp-frontend? I think that the command may not be executed from the correct directory.

Comment: @Trace the error I provided happens actually when executed right from the command line.

Comment: @Trace i edited my question with the full error

Comment: The command you need to execute is webpack without arguments. Webpack build is the id given to that maven goal. Current working directory should in your case be: myapp-frontend